# calling C functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, c, client-server, client-side, server-side

I'm using **javascript** to run a server.
I want **to call c function on the server side.** How can I call it?
I googled, most of the time there is info on how to use AJAX and .net to call the function.
The c function is alread build and saved in some location on the PC. 
I wanted to call this C function from the javascript on the server side

Anyone has any info regardin this? many many thanks.
Regards
Vish

Comment: Yeah, you can only run javascript on the client machine. So you will have to make an AJAX call to the server. Something on the server needs to handle this call, an then it can do what you need.... try something, and then come back and show us your code, with a more specific issue to resolve. It would also be very useful to understand what you mean by "call C function"

Comment: Are you using Node.js? If not take a look at that for some server-side js calling external stuff examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. Actually I am using BeagleBone Black which runs a web server by the code as give at the link https://github.com/simonmonk/prog_bbb.git Here in Prog BBB folder there are 2 files 09_01_led_control.js and 09_01_led_control.html . When we connect a beaglebone black and run these code, open the link 192.168.7.2:8085, we can see a simple GUI (On/OFF button).Now I want the server code (09_01_led_control.js) to call a C function which is   on the BeagleBone black. //SOrry for the comments. Pretty new to stackoverflow!THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could spawn a child process using the node `child_process` module.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var ls = spawn("ls", ["-l", "-a"], {stdio: "inherit"});

ls.on("exit", function(status) {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

See:
http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: thanks SImpleJ. I will check it. but how can the server know the location where the c function is saved? WE need to call the main.obj file. right? Actually there I have written a simple main.c file. build it into main.o I want to call this main.o file. thanks once again.

Comment: here is a good link which I'm trying to understand : http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/01/03/c-and-node-js-an-unholy-combination-but-oh-so-right/

Comment: You would compile your c program into an executable then run it using spawn. This doesn't call the function directly; it just runs the program containing the function. Based on your link, it looks like your trying to do something more in-depth than just spawning a process though.

Comment: thanks SimpleJ. I just got that link while googling. ok. I will try to understand your answer. 1 doubt: how can the javascript know the location of the object file? Thanks.

Comment: Javascript doesn't know the location of the object file. You would compile your `main.c` or `main.o` file into `main.exe` then run `spawn("path/to/main", ["arg1", "arg2", "etc"])` to run the executable from node.

Comment: Thanks SimpleJ! I will try it and let you know about the progress. Many thanks once again.

Comment: The java script which should call the C function is at the location of /var/lib/cloud9/demo In this location I have made a folder called gpio which has the Test executable file. 
Actually to run this c file directly from console i used to type ./Test. Now I want to call this function from javascript. plz check my 3 lines of code added:                                         var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;                       var ls = spawn("gpio/Test.exe", {stdio: "inherit"});                ls.on("exit", function(status) { console.log("Done"); })

Comment: Hi.How to give the full path of the exe file in linux? many Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SimpleJ : can you please guide me to call the C function (exe) from the javascript. I tried your suggested method but it is throwing an exception at 
** 'var ls=spawn("gpio/Test.exe")  '**
**How to provide the full path? **
There is a folder called **gpio** in the same location as the javascript. In that gpio folder there is the **Test.exe** How to give the path? 
many many thanks

Comment: Hey, I found the way to call the C executable from the javascript. Just these 3 lines are needed
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
//Here the Test Executable file is in the same folder as the //javascript file
    var ls = spawn("./Test",  {stdio: "inherit"});

  ls.on("exit", function(status)
  {
    console.log("Done");
  }
  );

**Many thanks! :-)**